# System settings not being saved on reboot

Tags: dual-boot

I'm running a dualboot with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. I have a few basic system settings that I want that are not the default (make my headset the default speakers, turn off the touchpad when a mouse is plugged in, etc.), but every time I change them, they change back when I reboot. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: How do you change them ?